# Random number for each element of a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a sequence of random numbers for a vector with length n=5. 
This is my code:

```
elements<-5
day<-30
t_time<-rep(day*runif(1), elements)
```

However something is wrong, also considering a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:elements){
t_time[i]<- day*runif(1)
}
```

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong? 
Many thanks.

Comment: You are just repeating the same 1 random value 5 times with `rep(day*runif(1), elements)`, just try `t_time <- day*runif(elements)` instead

Comment: Use `?runif` to see how the function works, then ask questions if you are having problems

Comment: Thank you, Relasta!

Comment: `runif(elements, 0, day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using `sample` function:

```
x <- sample(range, size)
```

So for instance

```
x <- sample(100, 5)
```

will return

```
[1] 92 21 70 38 31
```